# How Do I enable port forwarding but only for some IPs and block others?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, port-forwarding

I have a device running linux and currently all of my network traffic is going through it before going to my Wifi router. I used arp spoofing to get between my devices and my router and used the following command to enable port forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

As an example, how could I allow packets from 192.168.0.2 and block packets from 192.168.0.3?

Comment: that looks like a typical use case for a firewall, no?

Comment: that's probably what I will end up using, but I was wondering if there was a super simple one line command that I could use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netfilter can do that, e.g

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.0.2 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Comment: With your `DROP` policy won't you need a line to allow the returning packets?

Comment: @roaima I believe the conn track module or something similar does that automatically

Comment: Thought you needed something like `iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`. (You would for an `INPUT` chain with policy `DROP`, so I'm assuming it's also required for a `FORWARD` chain.)

Comment: @roaima Perhaps you're right about it, I haven't tested it